# Spring JPA : No converter data from DB in to DTO

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a custom query in my Repository. And I created a DTO interface like this:

```
public interface ImagePathAndID {
    String getImagePath();
    Integer getIdProduct();
}
```

My query is :

```
@Query(value = "select image.image_path, product.product_id from    image\r\n" + 
            "           inner join product  on product.product_id = image.product_id\r\n" + 
            "           inner join category as c on product.category_id = c.category_id \r\n" + 
            "           where c.category_id = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<ImagePathAndID > selectAllImagePathForCategory(@Param("id") int id);
```

And when I return data I get null value for  `getImagePath` and `getIdProduct`.

```
List<ImagePathAndID> imagePath = this.categoryRepository.selectAllImagePathForCategory(id);


        for (ImagePathAndID image:imagePath ) {
            System.out.println(image.getImagePath() + image.getIdProduct());
        }
```

I got the 3 object for `ImagePathAndID`  but value for this object is `null`.
Output is :

```
null,null
null,null
null,null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that the properties defined should exactly match the interface method naming convention. Refer [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

You should modify your query and interface methods like below.

**Query**

```
@Query(value ="select image.image_path as imagePath, product.product_id as productId from    image\r\n" + 
        "           inner join product  on product.product_id = image.product_id\r\n" + 
        "           inner join category as c on product.category_id = c.category_id \r\n" + 
        "           where c.category_id = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
public List<ImagePathAndID > selectAllImagePathForCategory(@Param("id") int id);
```

**Interface**

```
public interface ImagePathAndID {
   String getImagePath();
   Integer getProductId();
```

}